# I wanted to assign a key value depending on the multiple condition matched with the array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, arraylist, reduce

I have below array of object.

`

```
[
        {
            "work_package_id": 1,
            "work_package_name": "Status Audit",
            "work_package_number": 1,
            "successor": "2,3,4",
            "work_package_identifier": "Status Audit",
            "work_package_description": "After taking over the project, you must first get an overview of the original project plan and current status. Due to the high expectations of the site leadership team for the project; Teams are very committed on the Reviews and they do not delegate enough activities to third parties ",
            "work_package_cost": "60",
            "work_package_safety": "0",
            "work_package_quality": "0",
            "work_package_duration": "3",
            "work_package_buffer": "0",
            "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
            "work_package_rail_number": 1,
            "work_package_plot": {
                "x": 20,
                "y": 10,
                "label": [
                    "Status",
                    "Audit"
                ]
            },
            "work_package_links": [
                {
                    "x": 20,
                    "y": 500,
                    "label": [
                        "Project",
                        "Managem."
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "x": 120,
                    "y": 100,
                    "label": [
                        "Plan to",
                        "Play"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "x": 120,
                    "y": 300,
                    "label": [
                        "Lessons",
                        "Learned"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "scenario_id": null,
            "responsible_to": null,
            "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "created_by": null,
            "updated_by": null
        },
        {
            "work_package_id": 2,
            "work_package_name": "Project Management",
            "work_package_number": 2,
            "successor": "37",
            "work_package_identifier": "Project Managem",
            "work_package_description": "The project management tasks include defining the project organization, control of all preparation and planning tasks and the ongoing coordination and supervision of work during the execution phase. The project team consists of you and five temporary resources in the department.",
            "work_package_cost": "750",
            "work_package_safety": "0",
            "work_package_quality": "0",
            "work_package_duration": "60",
            "work_package_buffer": "15",
            "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
            "work_package_rail_number": 1,
            "work_package_plot": {
                "x": 20,
                "y": 500,
                "label": [
                    "Project",
                    "Managem."
                ]
            },
            "work_package_links": [],
            "scenario_id": null,
            "responsible_to": null,
            "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "created_by": null,
            "updated_by": null
        },
        {
            "work_package_id": 3,
            "work_package_name": "Plan to Play",
            "work_package_number": 3,
            "successor": "5,6,7,8,9,10",
            "work_package_identifier": "Plan to Play",
            "work_package_description": "The definition of the TAR strategy and project structure takes place at the beginning of the project. There will be questions about the TAR timeframe that will be agreed with Production, the plants will be divided into clusters and project phases will need to be adjusted. Above all there will be discussions regarding the integration of investment projects. (CAPEX)",
            "work_package_cost": "60",
            "work_package_safety": "0",
            "work_package_quality": "0",
            "work_package_duration": "2",
            "work_package_buffer": "0",
            "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
            "work_package_rail_number": 2,
            "work_package_plot": {
                "x": 120,
                "y": 100,
                "label": [
                    "Plan to",
                    "Play"
                ]
            },
            "work_package_links": [],
            "scenario_id": null,
            "responsible_to": null,
            "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "created_by": null,
            "updated_by": null
        },
        {
            "work_package_id": 4,
            "work_package_name": "Lessons Learned",
            "work_package_number": 4,
            "successor": "7,8,9,10",
            "work_package_identifier": "Lessons Learned",
            "work_package_description": "You analyze the \"lessons learned\"\" report from the last shutdown project. You are surprised to notice that many of the current problems also took place during the last shutdown. In discussions with the Site representatives you try to find the causes and the reason why improvements to the demonstrated conclusions have not been implemented so far.\"",
            "work_package_cost": "20",
            "work_package_safety": "0",
            "work_package_quality": "0",
            "work_package_duration": "2",
            "work_package_buffer": "4",
            "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
            "work_package_rail_number": 2,
            "work_package_plot": {
                "x": 120,
                "y": 300,
                "label": [
                    "Lessons",
                    "Learned"
                ]
            },
            "work_package_links": [],
            "scenario_id": null,
            "responsible_to": null,
            "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
            "created_by": null,
            "updated_by": null
        }
    ]
```

`

Now I want to compare each end every object with each other and assign key value to specific value depending on below condition

Codition 1 :- If object belongs to same work_package_rail_number and his work_package_buffer is 0 and work_package_rail_duration is greater than other object in same work_package_rail_number then assign key value is_critical:1 if multiple having same work_package_rail_duration and buffer 0 then multiple are critical.

Codition 2 :- If object belongs to same work_package_rail_number and his work_package_buffer is 0 and work_package_rail_duration is less than is_critical:1 object in same work_package_rail_number then assign key value is_critical:2 if multiple having same work_package_rail_duration and buffer 0 then multiple are is_critical:2.

Codition 2 :- If object belongs to same work_package_rail_number and his work_package_buffer is not 0 is_critical:3.

So i want to compare each object which is having same work_package_rail_number and assign value according to upper condition.

It should be rail wise -- group wise compare

1. critical = buffer -> should be zero duration should be maximum i.e is_critical:1
2. near critical = buffer -> should be greater than zero and duration should be maximum - 1 i.e is_critical:2
3. other i.e is_critical:3

Response is like below:-

`

```
[
    {
        "work_package_id": 1,
        "work_package_name": "Status Audit",
        "work_package_number": 1,
        "successor": "2,3,4",
        "work_package_identifier": "Status Audit",
        "work_package_description": "After taking over the project, you must first get an overview of the original project plan and current status. Due to the high expectations of the site leadership team for the project; Teams are very committed on the Reviews and they do not delegate enough activities to third parties ",
        "work_package_cost": "60",
        "work_package_safety": "0",
        "work_package_quality": "0",
        "work_package_duration": "3",
        "work_package_buffer": "0",
        "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
        "work_package_rail_number": 1,
        "work_package_plot": {
            "x": 20,
            "y": 10,
            "label": [
                "Status",
                "Audit"
            ]
        },
        "work_package_links": [
            {
                "x": 20,
                "y": 500,
                "label": [
                    "Project",
                    "Managem."
                ]
            },
            {
                "x": 120,
                "y": 100,
                "label": [
                    "Plan to",
                    "Play"
                ]
            },
            {
                "x": 120,
                "y": 300,
                "label": [
                    "Lessons",
                    "Learned"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "scenario_id": null,
        "responsible_to": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "created_by": null,
        "updated_by": null,
        "is_critical":2
    },
    {
        "work_package_id": 2,
        "work_package_name": "Project Management",
        "work_package_number": 2,
        "successor": "37",
        "work_package_identifier": "Project Managem",
        "work_package_description": "The project management tasks include defining the project organization, control of all preparation and planning tasks and the ongoing coordination and supervision of work during the execution phase. The project team consists of you and five temporary resources in the department.",
        "work_package_cost": "750",
        "work_package_safety": "0",
        "work_package_quality": "0",
        "work_package_duration": "60",
        "work_package_buffer": "15",
        "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
        "work_package_rail_number": 1,
        "work_package_plot": {
            "x": 20,
            "y": 500,
            "label": [
                "Project",
                "Managem."
            ]
        },
        "work_package_links": [],
        "scenario_id": null,
        "responsible_to": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "created_by": null,
        "updated_by": null,
        "is_critical": 1
    },
    {
        "work_package_id": 3,
        "work_package_name": "Plan to Play",
        "work_package_number": 3,
        "successor": "5,6,7,8,9,10",
        "work_package_identifier": "Plan to Play",
        "work_package_description": "The definition of the TAR strategy and project structure takes place at the beginning of the project. There will be questions about the TAR timeframe that will be agreed with Production, the plants will be divided into clusters and project phases will need to be adjusted. Above all there will be discussions regarding the integration of investment projects. (CAPEX)",
        "work_package_cost": "60",
        "work_package_safety": "0",
        "work_package_quality": "0",
        "work_package_duration": "2",
        "work_package_buffer": "0",
        "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
        "work_package_rail_number": 2,
        "work_package_plot": {
            "x": 120,
            "y": 100,
            "label": [
                "Plan to",
                "Play"
            ]
        },
        "work_package_links": [],
        "scenario_id": null,
        "responsible_to": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "created_by": null,
        "updated_by": null,
        "is_critical": 1
    },
    {
        "work_package_id": 4,
        "work_package_name": "Lessons Learned",
        "work_package_number": 4,
        "successor": "7,8,9,10",
        "work_package_identifier": "Lessons Learned",
        "work_package_description": "You analyze the \"lessons learned\"\" report from the last shutdown project. You are surprised to notice that many of the current problems also took place during the last shutdown. In discussions with the Site representatives you try to find the causes and the reason why improvements to the demonstrated conclusions have not been implemented so far.\"",
        "work_package_cost": "20",
        "work_package_safety": "0",
        "work_package_quality": "0",
        "work_package_duration": "2",
        "work_package_buffer": "4",
        "work_package_status_name": "notstarted",
        "work_package_rail_number": 2,
        "work_package_plot": {
            "x": 120,
            "y": 300,
            "label": [
                "Lessons",
                "Learned"
            ]
        },
        "work_package_links": [],
        "scenario_id": null,
        "responsible_to": null,
        "date_created": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "date_updated": "2022-11-17T08:53:26.000Z",
        "created_by": null,
        "updated_by": null,
        "is_critical":2
    }
]
```

`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to compare each and every object if work_package_rail_number is same compare that object and assign value is_critical to it depending on below
If work_package_buffer is 0 and work_package_rail_duration then make that object as critical package means add key is_critical:1 to it.
If If work_package_buffer is 0 and work_package_rail_duration is less that critical package then make that object as less critical package means add key is_critical:2 to it.
otherwise make it is_critical:3